# Android Compose Material3 - How can one add both TopAppBar and Tabs under it in the same layout?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, tabs, android-jetpack-compose, appbar

I am using Android Studio with Jetpack Compose and Material 3.  I want to create bot a topappbar and below it multiple tabs.  In Material 3, Scaffold is defined as :

```
@Composable
fun Scaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    snackbarHost: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButtonPosition: FabPosition = FabPosition.End,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(containerColor),
    contentWindowInsets: WindowInsets = ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets,
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
): Unit
```

When I assign a TopAppBar to topBar parameter, it works.  Likewise if I add a TopRow with Tab(s) to topBar parameter, this also works.  But how do I add a TopAppBar with Tab(s) below it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
 @Composable
 fun CustomTopBarWithTabs(
     title: String,
     selectedTabIndex: Int,
     changeTabIndex: (Int) -> Unit,
     modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
     behavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior = 
 TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(),
 ) {
     val tabs = listOf("Home", "Settings", "Profile")
     Column(
         modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
     ) {
         CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
             scrollBehavior = behavior,
             title = {Text(title)}
         )
         TabRow(
             selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
         ) {
             tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tabTitle ->
                 Tab(
                     modifier = Modifier.height(36.dp),
                     selected = selectedTabIndex == index,
                     onClick = { changeTabIndex(index) }
                 ) {
                     Text(text = tabTitle)
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Create new file, and put the function inside the topBar parameter.

Hope it works! :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Raka M.A Your solution worked.  But now I see a problem.  TopAppBar has an anination feature - while scrolling the contents its container color changes.  However, such a feature is not available in TabRow.  How would we do this?

Answer (score 0):

I typically do it like this:

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = { CenterAlignedTopAppBar() },
    content = {
        innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            TabRow(scrollState)
            Content(scrollState)
        }
    
    }
)
```

And if you want to raise its elevation just like the `topBar` when content scrolling ,maybe you could write an animation and listen the change of `scrollState`

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  topBar = {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
      TopAppBarCustom()
      TabsCustom()
    }
  },
  bottomBar = {
    BottomBarCustom()
  }
) {

}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.